# Can we avoid Prefix and Separator for Repeatable migrations in Flyway?

Tags: flyway

I want to Use [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) to an existing large MSSQL database which has about 1000 number of stored procedures. In order to use [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) I need to rename the stored proc's by adding the prefix. Is there any way that we can do without renaming the stored proc's ?

Comment: Do you really need one migration script for each stored procedure?

Comment: what do you mean by one migration script ? as far as i know we don't have to use any migration script. We give the path of the SQL folder in Flyway config file and Flyway will handle the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you want to start migrating from the current state, or do you want your migration scripts to include your 1000 stored procedures?

Comment: I want to include the 1000 stored procedures. That is the correct way of doing it i guess. Then only when we do a modification to any one of those, [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) will identify it as modified and run the stored proc again.

Comment: Have you tried to use Flyway yet? I don't get the impression from your question and comments that you have. I'd recommend that you give it a go, and when you come across a specific issue, you post it here.

Comment: I do use [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/). I was able to version the database successfully using it. what i wanted here is to know that if anybody had tried using [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) by overriding its default config Because i have an existing database with 1000 stored proc's so renaming them is the only option in order to use  [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/).